# Visual Studio no me muestra todas las versiones de Android descargadas - SDK Manager

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio desarrollando una app con **Xamarin.Android** pero me encontré con un problema que me esta dando mucho dolor de cabeza porque me impide la descarga de los NuGets que necesito (`Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging`).

El problema principal es que descargue prácticamente todas las versiones de Android desde el **SDK Manager**, pero al momento de querer seleccionar Android 9 (API 28) o Android 10 como "Target Android Version", me muestra todas hasta el Android 8, osea, no me muestra ni el Android 9 ni nada mas arriba.

Ya he probado a actualizar, desinstalar los paquetes y volverlos a instalar, y nada funciona.

[image: Error Xamarin]

[image: SDK Manager]

[image: VS1]

[image: VS2]

Algun consejo? Al menos para poder instalar el NuGet, lo necesito para poder implementar las notificaciones Push en mi app?

Comment: Abre el SDK desde Visual Studio --- Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager
puedes checar ahi cuales tienes o si el platforms tools necesite actualizarse

Comment: Ya lo solucione @Luis, era debido a que mi version de uso de VS2017 (15.4.5.) no permitía usar APIs nuevas como la 9+ (las podia instalar pero no usar en dispositivos virtuales). Migre a VS2019 y Problem Solved. Saludos